# Angular 2 CLI: ng test error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've set up a new temp app with `ng new my-app`, and when I run `ng test` I get the following error:

`The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with: 
    Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '../src/tsconfig.json'`

I was wondering if anyone else had encountered this issue and found a way around it.

Comment: Found that it is a pretty common issue. Running `ng test --watch false` seems like the best work around for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "**ng test --build=false**"